# Oracle error "name of the package and name of schema must match with editing object"

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to build a package, I use the following code for specs

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE MBA.OSA
        AS
          FUNCTION FUNC_OSA 
          (inp_SKU in number, func_store_id in number, func_start_date in DATE, func_end_date in DATE)
          RETURN NUMBER;
        END OSA;
```

and following for body

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY MBA.OSA as

function FUNC_OSA  (inp_SKU in number, func_store_id in number, func_start_date in DATE, func_end_date in DATE) RETURN NUMBER
IS 
p_OSA NUMBER;
BEGIN
with period_len as (
select (func_end_date - func_start_date) len_per from dual
),
OSA_ as (
select dm.SKU,
      dm.store_id,
     ROUND(count(distinct dm.TRAN_DATE) / (select len_per from period_len) * 100,0) OSA
    --into OSA
    from datamarts.SALES_DETAIL_DM dm
    where SKU = inp_SKU
    AND TRAN_DATE between func_start_date and func_end_date
    AND dm.store_id = func_store_id
group by dm.SKU, dm.store_id
)
select OSA into p_OSA from OSA_;

RETURN p_OSA;
END FUNC_OSA;

END OSA;
```

But I keep getting the same error:

```
name of the package and name of schema must match with editing object
```

Name of schema is MBA, it is in Package name and package body also. Editing object, I guess, is my function func_osa, but if I add the name of scheme like MBA.FUNC_OSA, I get bunch or errors.

Comment: You can remove the select from dual and just put func_end_date-func_start_date in place of both selects. But this is NOT the cause of the error. What is the user_id logging into this session, MBA or DM or ...?

Comment: @Katya: is there an ORA- number that goes with that error? It doesn't sound like any Oracle message I've ever seen or heard of. Are you logged in as the MBA user? And what tool are you using to do your editing and compiling with? ???

Comment: It compiles fine for me if I remove the hardcoded schema names and create a `sales_detail_dm` table. I suspect this is a tool-related issue. What are you using, and is that the whole error message?

Comment: There is no ORA number, just this text string (I translated it from Russian). This is the whole error message. My tool is Aqua studio 18.0.1 About user_id - I have no idea, sorry..

Comment: @WilliamRobertson, sorry I don't get it, could you please provide the code?

Comment: @Katya I'm saying I used your code and it did not give me any errors. The only changes I made were to remove the schema names, as I don't have an `MBA` or `DATAMARTS` schema, and I created a dummy `sales_detail_dm` table. What username are you using to connect to Oracle? (From [screenshots](https://www.aquaclusters.com/app/home/project/public/aquadatastudio/wikibook/Documentation19/page/10/attachment/B9C55C72-BA21-8F2E-FB6F-81ECF384C5C7/package-editing-png) that I can find, it seems Aqua Studio displays the current schema name above the code editing panel.)

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
connect / as sysdba
alter session set current_schema=MBA;
**CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE OSA**
..
END OSA;
/
**CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY OSA**
..
END OSA;
/
```